# Findin numbers in txt by reg expression, small problem

Tags: python

I wrote the code, however, it is finding only the first number in the line, and I am kind of stuck. So if there are 2 or more numbers in line in getting only 1, what am I doing wrong? I am a beginner.

```
import re
fhand = open('text2.txt','r')
numlist = list()
total = 0
for line in fhand:


      line = line.rstrip()
      numbers = re.findall(r'[0-9]+', line)
      if len(numbers) < 1: continue
      for element in numbers :
        num = float(numbers[0])
      if num not in numlist:
          numlist.append(num)
      else : continue
      sumlist = sum(numlist)
print(numlist)
print(sumlist)
```

http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/regex_sum_228867.txt that's the text file I am using and my sum is 191882, and the result should much bigger because my text is reading the only first number from a line. Cheers guys I will be grateful

Comment: `element` is unused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comment melpomene already answered but in case you need to see, change your code to

```
for element in numbers :
        num = float(element)
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this (use re.M) to pass a multi-line flag.

```
with open('text2.txt') as f:
  s = sum(map(float,re.findall(r'[0-9]+', f.read(), re.M)))
  print(s)
```

Returns:

```
425922.0
```